# Android java json url from dropbox

Tags: android, json, url, dropbox

I have this piece of code on android that reads data from Assets folder, so I need from this code to read data from external like dropbox. Ho to change and read data from dropbox. thanks

```
@Override
protected RadioDatas doInBackground(Void... params) {
BufferedReader reader = null;
ArrayList<RadioData> radioDatas = new ArrayList<>();
RadioDatas datas = new RadioDatas();
try {
reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("url.txt"), "Unicode"));


String mLine;
while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
RadioData radioData = new RadioData();
String[] meta = mLine.split(";");
radioData.setUrl(meta[0]);
radioData.setTitle(meta[1]);
radioData.setGenres(meta[2]);
radioDatas.add(radioData);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
//log the exception
return null;
} finally {
if (reader != null) {
try {
reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
//log the exception
}
}
}

datas.setRadioDatas(radioDatas);
return datas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work....

```
public class Execute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpHandler handler = new HttpHandler();
        String jsonString = handler.makeServiceCall(json);
        if (jsonString != null) {
            try {

                //parse jsonString

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i("Error with parsing", e.getMessage());

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

You will need a HTTPHandler class...

```
public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

To run it.

```
new Execute().execute;
```

Comment: hi. I cpied this code but again it says error. Can you edit my page and send to me:

Comment: here I uploaded in dropbox, please see and edit to read my url from dropbox. thanks very much

Comment: you need to use a .json file.dont just copy code, understand it. its the EXACT code I used to my execute class... so this works

Comment: you said json url.... yet you are still calling in a .txt. do you know what json is? its not a .txt file, thats for sure.

Comment: I dont understand very much because I needed help. If you can edit the file that I sent with dropbox end make to call file from external. thanks very much

Comment: im not editing your file. you obviously have no idea what you want.